# How do I use arithmetic symbols instead of built in functions

Tags: python, math

I am making a maths quiz in python and am using 3 operators: add, subtract and multiply. I want to use arithmetic operators but I am finding it difficult because python just reads it as a symbol if i just print it. I use the following code:

```
import random
import operator
opslist = [          # This is the bit that I want to change, i also want 
    operator.add,    # the operators all on one line
    operator.sub,
    operator.mul
]

num1 = random.randint(1,10)  # These are two random numbers for my quiz
num2 = random.randint(1,10)
ops = random.choice(opslist) #Random operator for my quiz

total = (ops(num1,num2))    # Answer for my quiz

print (num1,ops,num2)       # Random question for my quiz
```

Here is the ouput:

```
6 <built-in function add> 5
```

1.) how do I make the output "6+5"

2.) Also, how do I make the numbers only do small calculations that result in positive answers so the question can never be something like "5-8"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use a dictionary also in your code. This is what I did.

```
import random
import operator

opslist= {
    operator.add: "+",    # the operators all on one line
    operator.sub: "-",
    operator.mul: "x"
}

num1 = random.randint(1,10)  # These are two random numbers for my quiz
num2 = random.randint(1,10)
ops = random.choice(list(opslist.keys())) #Random operator from opslist keys

total = (ops(num1,num2)) # Answer for my quiz

print(num1,opslist[ops],num2)
```

When printing the question, the program prints out the sign for the operator. To make it sure that you don't get negative numbers add this under total:

```
while total < 0:
    num1 = random.randint(1,10)
    num2 = random.randint(1,10)
    ops = random.choice(opslist)

    total = (ops(num1,num2))
```

Comment: Is there a way to combine both the "opslist" and opslistsymbols" so I can use less lines and make the code more efficient

Comment: Got an error: `print(num1,opslistsymbols[ops],num2)
NameError: name 'opslistsymbols' is not defined`

Comment: micheal can you answer my other question on my account?

Comment: Michealpri you're negative numbers code does not seem efficient to me. This is because I'm repeating all the variables i declared earlier such as num1, num2 etc. Is there any way to avoid negative numbers and not repeat code so that it is efficient.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a dictionary to map an operation to its symbolic representation. Also you can add some logic for subtraction, to ensure `num2` is lower than `num1`:

```
import random
import operator
ops = {
    operator.add: '+', 
    operator.sub: '-',
    operator.mul: '*'
}
num1, num2 = random.randint(1, 10), random.randint(1, 10)
op = random.choice(ops.keys())
if op != operator.sub or num2 <= num1:
    print "%d %s %d = %d" % (num1, ops[op], num2, op(num1, num2))
```

Possible result:

```
3 - 2 = 1
```

Comment: You can replace the prints with either one of these to get a "clean" output without quotes:
`print("%d %s %d = %d" % (num1, ops[op], num2, op(num1, num2)))`
or if you don't want to spoil the answer:
`print("%d %s %d" % (num1, ops[op], num2))`

Comment: Looks good! michealpri 's answer has a better way of generating new sets of num1, num2 if the constraints aren't met (e.g. num2 < num1) but this approach is cleaner since it combines both the ops list and dictionary in one

Comment: Just showed a way... For me even negative numbers are valid.

Comment: JuniorCompressor your code gives me an error of: "TypeError: 'dict_keys' object does not support indexing". It tells me `op = random.choice(ops.keys())` is the problem.

Comment: You are using python3.  Change to `op = random.choice(list(ops.keys()))`